# Is it mandatory to validate in my server the ID token with Google Sign in?

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-signin, google-authentication

I implemented a simple web page where Google Sign In let users enter their Gmail and password in order to authenticate; then I made a simple server with Flask using  [Google Python API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth).

Everything is working fine, but I realized that I made the server before asking myself if I really need it: if I got it right, when user's credentials are verified after clicking on Google Sign In, the user is authenticated.

Client-side speaking, after a successful login a `GoogleUser` object is returned and it contains informations about the user; however, the user has already told me who he is since he provided me username and password.

**So, why bother validating on a server an ID token if it is given after a successful login?**

Some concepts sound contradictory to me: [Google Sign-In for Websites: Authentication with backends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_673138331&feature=iv&index=2&list=PLNYkxOF6rcIBQCKXOfi4AUtSpMj78pX5f&src_vid=Oy5F9h5JqEU&v=j_31hJtWjlw) video says that:

> You can obtain an ID token upon the successful authentication

this would mean that the user is who he claims to be, but then, speaking about a server:

> Note that the client libraries verify most of the information, but you still have to check if *aud* and *iss* claims are correct [on the server]

I thought that these two claims were verified on the client.

Is the `GoogleUser` object returned from a successful login enough to say "he is really that user"?

The ID token I send and verify in my server is necessary because there is no Google Sign-in button on the servers and is meant only for client side code?

Answer (score 0):

> So, why bother validating on a server an ID token if it is given after
>   a successful login?

The OAuth 2.0 ID Token provides the "verified" identity of the client. Since it is very easy to create an ID Token, you need to verify that the ID Token was created by a trusted Identity Provider. You verify the ID Token to prevent forgery attacks. How? By using the public key from the Identity Provider to verify the signature attached to the ID Token.

> Note that the client libraries verify most of the information, but you
>   still have to check if aud and iss claims are correct [on the server]
>
> I thought that these two claims were verified on the client.

In terms of security, you cannot trust anything from the client. You must verify everything. Hackers today think nothing of running scripts attacking any resource attached to a public IP address.

> Is the GoogleUser object returned from a successful login enough to
>   say "he is really that user"?

No. The JavaScript code running at the browser can be modified. This means all data coming from the browser to your server should be consider "untrusted".

> The ID token I send and verify in my server is necessary because there
>   is no Google Sign-in button on the servers and is meant only for
>   client side code?

You can implement 3-legged OAuth 2.0 which puts your server into the Authorization process. This way your server receives the Access Token, Refresh Token and ID Token. You then control what you provide to the client.